# django sending emails

Tags: django, email, send

Hay, i can't seem to send emails using send_mail(), and I'm not sure why.

Here's my details

**settins.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost',
EMAIL_PORT = 25
```

**My view**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

This fails with the error

```
getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None
```

Anyone have any ideas?

I'm developing on OS X Leopard

Heres the last traceback

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/smtplib.py in connect
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM): ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
host    ('localhost',)
msg     'getaddrinfo returns an empty list'
port    25
self    <smtplib.SMTP instance at 0x153b1e8>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comma after `EMAIL_HOST` is making it a tuple of length one instead of a string. Remove the stray comma.

Comment: and just like that my problem was solved! Thank you VERY much!